# What is the gtk-rs design pattern for changing the widgets on a page?

Tags: rust, gtk4, gtk-rs

I am using `gtk-rs` to build a small application and I am struggling with the concept of changing the widgets displayed on a page. So far I have been working through [this guide](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/book/introduction.html) but I have not found the information I am looking for.

An example would be you open the app and you start on the landing page, you then click a button and it takes you to another page/view which has different widgets on it.

I know how to build a page with a single set of widgets, I can update the contents of those widgets but I don't know how to either load a completely new layout or remove widgets and replace them.

Has anyone got a link to a guide or something similar detailing how to do this? If this isn't the way we're supposed to do this with `gtk-rs` can you point me to something detailing how we should be doing this?

I have been googling things like `gtk-rs redraw window`, `gtk-rs change widgets`, `gtk-rs new view` but none of these have returned an explanation of how to handle this problem.

An example from the guide is below. Assuming we pressed the button in this application I would then want to load a page with different buttons on it.

```
fn main() {
    // Create a new application
    let app = Application::builder().application_id(APP_ID).build();

    // Connect to "activate" signal of `app`
    app.connect_activate(build_ui);

    // Run the application
    app.run();
}

fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    // Create a button
    let button = Button::builder()
        .label("Press me!")
        .margin_top(12)
        .margin_bottom(12)
        .margin_start(12)
        .margin_end(12)
        .build();

    // Connect to "clicked" signal of `button`
    button.connect_clicked(move |_| {
        println!("The button was pressed!");
    });

    // Create a window
    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .title("My GTK App")
        .child(&button)
        .build();

    // Present window
    window.present();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just create a new `Window` and make that one visible? https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/0.2/docs/gtk4/struct.Window.html

Comment: I hadn’t tried but I will and I’ll get back to you with the results 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `Stack` for this purpose. Here, have a look at this [link](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk4/struct.Stack.html). Use `StackPage` to add pages.

Here's an example.

```
use gtk::Application;
use gtk::{prelude::*, ApplicationWindow};
use gtk::StackTransitionType::SlideLeftRight;

fn main() {

    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("com.artognak.markiv")
        .build();

    app.connect_activate(build_ui);

    app.run();
}

fn build_ui(app: &Application) {

    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .default_width(360)
        .default_height(360)
        .build();

    let container = gtk::Box::new(gtk::Orientation::Vertical, 100);
    window.set_child(Some(&container));

    let stack = gtk::Stack::new();

    stack.set_transition_type(SlideLeftRight);
    stack.set_transition_duration(200);

    let page_1_label = gtk::Label::new(Some("Page 1"));
    stack.add_titled(&page_1_label, Option::<&str>::None, "Page 1");

    let page_2_label = gtk::Label::new(Some("Page 2"));
    stack.add_titled(&page_2_label, Option::<&str>::None, "Page 2");

    let stack_switcher = gtk::StackSwitcher::new();
    stack_switcher.set_stack(Some(&stack));

    container.append(&stack_switcher);
    container.append(&stack);

    window.present();
}
```

You can also switch pages by setting the visible child name for the `Stack`. This way you won't need `StackSwitcher`.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I wanted. Thank you.